# Javascript get RFID using Sony NFC?

Tags: javascript, nfc, sony-xperia

Is there anyway to connect with Sony´s NFC reader and Javascript to get the IDs from the reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is impossible unless you write your own app that exposes nfc into a web frame.

well.. you could use phonegap:
http://phonegap.com/2011/09/26/building-an-nfc-enabled-android-application-with-phonegap/

Comment: It's pitty, there are some NFC, and RFID readers that acts as a human keyboard interface (As  keyboard), they fill any text box or area with the ID even in the web application (HTML) then you work from there. I'm thinking about Intel XDK or PhoneGap but I don't have that much time. Thanks for your help